# Show that a certain map $V \to \mathbb R$ is an element of the dual Space $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a vector space $V = \operatorname{Mat}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Define $\varphi:V\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}\right) = 2a+b$$

Prove that $\varphi\in V^*$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\varphi$ is visibly linear. But I don't get why you have to write out the four matrices $A_i$.

Comment: Those four matrices form a basis of $V$, so I guess the next question is to decompose $\varphi$ in the dual basis.

Comment: @Andreas, this is a second part of a question, and I didn't get the question and concepts so I just copied the question. Didn't know if we need it or not.

Comment: I believe @deufeufeu made the right guess.

Comment: Yes your right, the first part of the question asks us to prove they are the basis, for V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question, please edit if wrong.

Lets have $\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\c_1 & d_1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\c_2 & d_2\end{pmatrix}\in V$ and $k,l \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\varphi\left(k\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\c_1 & d_1\end{pmatrix}+l\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\c_2 & d_2\end{pmatrix}\right)=2(a_1k+a_2l)+(b_1k+b_2l)$$
$$=k(2a_1+b_1)+l(2a_2+b_2)$$
$$=k\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\c_1 & d_1\end{pmatrix}\right)+l\left(\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\c_2 & d_2\end{pmatrix}\right)$$

So $\varphi$ is linear map, hence $\varphi \in V^*$

Comment: +1. To be complete (although it might be trivial), shouldn't you also show that additive laws hold for $\varphi$?

Comment: @rbm, yes you are completely right, i just forgot to put it in, but yes its incomplete.